# Update a specific index from the array in Firestore

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i want to update a specific index of my array but i get this

" type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'".

Does anyone know why I am getting this error ?

```
                 Checkbox(
                    value: widget.raffles[index]
                        ["${auth.currentUser.uid}" + "link"],
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() {
                        sneakers.doc(widget.doc).set(
                          {
                            widget.raffles[index]: [
                              {
                                "${auth.currentUser.uid}" + "link": true,
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          SetOptions(merge: true),
                        );
                      });
                    },
                  ),
```